# I can't find older version of Wubi!

Tags: 11.10, wubi, versions

here it arrive only to 2009
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wubi/files/Wubi/

how is possible?
I need wubi 11.10!!!

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/

Or after May 9th, 2013 (when support ends for 11.10) it will be available at: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

After support has ended [soon for 11.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), you won't get security updates. Therefore it's recommended to install a supported release.

Comment: i'm blind!!! i'm just see that page but i don't find it!! thanks!! i'm istalling it just now...